# Мультиплеер на андройд - Unity

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-android

Планирую создать 2D шутер-платформер (2 игрока друг с другом стреляются). Выпустить хочу на Android и ещё рекламу впихать в приложение. Через что лучше мультиплеер реализовать (и что читать), чтобы это сделать? Или это вообще сложно для новичка в Unity? Пока что реализовал через Network в юнити, но там пули и Scale не отображается.

Answer (score 0):

[Вот серия коротких уроков  от Unity](https://unity3d.com/ru/learn/tutorials/s/multiplayer-networking).
 Там вам и примеры кода и пояснения, как отображать пули и синхронизировать Scale.